# How to integrate the following. (Integration over open sets)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

We saw how to integrate the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ over the interval $(0,1,)$ then we first want to know if it is integrable the we do the following, we choose a admisible cover for $(0,1)$ as the one forme by $U_n = (1/2^{n+1},1/2^{n-1})$ for $n=1,2,3,...$

We suppose tha the partition of the unity subordinate to the cover is $F=\{\phi_n : n=1,2,... \}$, where each supp$\phi_n \subset U_n$.

Then:

$$\int_{(0,1)} \phi_n f \leq \int_{U_n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx \leq \int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{1/2^{n-1}} \sqrt{2^{n+1}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}$$

But How did they get the last integral?, this is How is this $\int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{1/2^{n-1}} \sqrt{2^{n+1}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}$ possible? and well is the same proceedment for $f(x)=1/x^{p}$ right? where $p<1$ thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{1/2^{n-1}} \sqrt{2^{n+1}}=\sqrt{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\sqrt{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\sqrt{2^{n+1}}\frac{3}{2^{n+1}}$$

which is equal to $\frac{3}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}.$

Also, you can repeat the same argument for any $p\in(0,1).$

Comment: thanks a lot ;) then how do you get the 4 and the one in the above answer?

Comment: When you write both fractions with same denominator. Note that $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{2}{2^n}=\frac{4}{2^{n+1}}.$

Comment: Right ;) jajajaja I got it, then if I want to know and integrate 1/x^p I can do the same proceedment right? only interchanging the 1/2 by p :)

Comment: Yes. You can do it in the same way.

Comment: right thanks a lot :) for your help, so elementary, I was lost :)

Comment: You're welcome.